# How to use background: url(); in Bootstrap 4v6?

Tags: html, css, background-image, bootstrap-4

I am currently coding a website using Bootstrap 4v6 where I am using section tags. In addition I want my  to have background images. Normally, I would call the background image in css by :

```
#collection {
background: url('assets/img/man-dressed.jpg') center center no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
.collection-text {
background: rgba (0,0,0,0.8);
color: white;
padding: 1.875 rem;
}
```

But for some reason, it is not pulling showing the image. I have double check my file directory and it is showing a gap white space where the image is supposed to be, but no results or documentation. Is there an alterative way to call the background image in css in Bootstrap 4v6?

```
<section id="collection">
      <div class="collection-content">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="collection-text">
      <h3>Upcoming Sales </h3>
      <p class="lead">The important thing is to take your time and not get stressed. It pains me physically to see a woman victimized, rendered pathetic, by fashion. Those fashion designers are just crazy; but aren't we all? Attention to detail is of utmost importance when you want to look good. I am convinced that there can be luxury in simplicity.</p>

      <p>The important thing is to take your time and not get stressed. It pains me physically to see a woman victimized, rendered pathetic, by fashion. Those fashion designers are just crazy; but aren't we all? Attention to detail is of utmost importance when you want to look good. I am convinced that there can be luxury in simplicity.</p>
      <h5>View More Collections</h5>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary-outline">Fall Collection</a>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary-outline">Spring Collection</a>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary-outline">Summer Collection</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Hero Section w/blank image] [image: Fashion Collection Section w/blank image]

Comment: Check your file path. Are you seeing any error messages in the log?

Comment: Nope, no error logs.

Comment: @Ihazkode I double checked the error log, now it is saying source can not be found but the images are clearly in my assets/img folder. I even copied the full path twice in Atom so this won't happen. I don't think it is a corrupted file because all of the other images that are being called via <img src=""> works perfectly fine, and they are all in the same folder.

Comment: [just in case it's the file path](https://image.ibb.co/dCS6Ga/Capture.png) - Source: [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I did not know about the third option. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you sorted it out.